# Problems while running an web application on Cloudbees

Tags: cloudbees

I am trying to access one service from the application which I deployed on cloudbees but I receive 500 error and a big stacktrace. It fails because it cannot open the JPA EntityManager due to CommunicationsException: Communications link failure due to underlying exception: ... java.net.SocketException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused .

The database configuration seems fine because tests on Jenkins successfully connect to the DB from cloudbees and insert data.

If I do a deploy on localhost (and using the local mysql) all services work fine.

Can anyone suggest what might be the problem?
Thanks

Comment: If needed, I can provide the stacktrace or other configurations.

Comment: Try deploying on localhost using remote database to double check credentials. Do you use datasource binding or declaration in cloudbees-web.xml ?

Comment: Hi. The deploy on localhost with the remote db works fine - I can acces resources that read the remote database. I use a normal spring configuration for the datasource binding, without the cludbees-web.xml.Thanks

Comment: Hello again. After a deploy this morning it started to work.I have no idea why it was failing before since I didn't commit anything to svn. Sorry for bothering. Regards

Answer (score 0):

Fixed without additional configuration - just a new deploy.